# Is it possible to know when scrolling a div with overflow: scroll reached the end?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get new data when reaching the end of the content of a div element with `overflow: scroll`

I have searched for an example of this but to with no success. I have researched on MDN and found the [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) event, in the event I found the [LayerY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerY) property

The method I thought might work is as follows. When scrolling down and if the value of the `LayerY` property is repeated `n` times, it is at the end of the content, so I make the call to the resource.

For example

```js
let repeat = 0;
let value = 0;

const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('wheel', wheelHandler);

function wheelHandler(event) {
    if (value > 150 && value === event.layerY) {
        repeat += 1;
    }

    if (value > 150 && repeat > 3) {
        console.log('fetch data');
        repeat = 0; // set repeat to 0 after fetch data
    }

    value = event.layerY;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
 width: 500px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 overflow: scroll;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed exercitationem
    doloribus cum, atque quibusdam nemo dolorem, quia omnis, libero consequatur
    molestiae error facilis maxime pariatur delectus aliquam sunt porro vel.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed exercitationem
    doloribus cum, atque quibusdam nemo dolorem, quia omnis, libero consequatur
    molestiae error facilis maxime pariatur delectus aliquam sunt porro vel.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed exercitationem
    doloribus cum, atque quibusdam nemo dolorem, quia omnis, libero consequatur
    molestiae error facilis maxime pariatur delectus aliquam sunt porro vel.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed exercitationem
    doloribus cum, atque quibusdam nemo dolorem, quia omnis, libero consequatur
    molestiae error facilis maxime pariatur delectus aliquam sunt porro vel.
</div>
```

There are other scenarios, for example handle if you scroll up

Is there a native way to achieve the expected result? either is this path correct

I appreciate your advice and ideas

Comment: when `.scrollheight - .clientheight - .scrollTop === 0`

Comment: are you trying to detect for any specific elements end or just the scroll bar end ?

Comment: I just want to know if scrolling reached the bottom of the content of the div

Comment: it's when `x.scrollheight - x.clientheight - x.scrollTop === 0` - where `x` is the element that is scrolling

Comment: Thanks for answering @Bravo but I do not get `scrollheight` `clientheight` `scrollTop` in event.

Comment: an event isn't an HTMLElement ... but an event contains an HTMLElement as the target property - in your code, it may even be `this` - so, use `this` for x, or `event.target` as appropriate to your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting if a scrollable DIV has reached the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148685/detecting-if-a-scrollable-div-has-reached-the-bottom)

Comment: @Nick - that answer uses jqueery - so would be as inappropriate as it gets

Comment: Or perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom-not-just-the-window-but-any-element) (2nd answer is JS) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)

Comment: @Bravo oops yes I pasted the wrong link. But I've added a couple more that have JS only solutions

Comment: i would suggest not to depend on `onwheel` instead of `onscroll` event as it will only trigger with mouse wheel but if you scroll by dragging scrollbar it will not trigger where `onscroll` trigger in most case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually i have spent a bit more time and explained it a bit more but if you spent some time reading it will be useful to understand everything

so i have created a little widget that's shows current details and also i have attached a diagram to clear things visually

[diagram image](https://ibb.co/Fxz0ybL)

```js
const main = document.querySelector(".items")
const vals = document.querySelectorAll(".vals")
    
main.onscroll = e => {
    let st = main.scrollTop,
        sh = main.scrollHeight,
        ch = main.clientHeight,
        scrollEnded = st + ch >= sh
    vals[0].innerHTML = st
    vals[1].innerHTML = sh
    vals[2].innerHTML = ch
    vals[3].innerHTML = st + ch
    vals[4].innerHTML = scrollEnded ? `<div class="bg-green-500 p-1 px-2 rounded-md text-white">end</div>`:`<div class="bg-red-500 p-1 px-2 rounded-md text-white">not-end</div>`
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="root flex justify-start">    
    <!-- main scroll element -->
    <div class="items p-5 border bg-gray-50 w-64 h-36 overflow-y-scroll">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste dolorem doloribus consequatur modi eius necessitatibus. Doloremque, eligendi rerum consequuntur delectus quisquam voluptatum harum, architecto eveniet commodi fugiat aliquid nemo iste?
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste dolorem doloribus consequatur modi eius necessitatibus. Doloremque, eligendi rerum consequuntur delectus quisquam voluptatum harum, architecto eveniet commodi fugiat aliquid nemo iste?
    </div>
    
<!-- extra demo thing -->
    <div class="details p-2 text-sm font-normal top-0 w-[400px] bg-gray-100">
        <div class="each-values flex">
            <div class="mr-2">scroll-top</div>
            <div class="vals"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="each-values flex">
            <div class="mr-2">scroll-height</div>
            <div class="vals"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="each-values flex">
            <div class="mr-2">client-height</div>
            <div class="vals"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="each-values flex">
            <div class="mr-2">scroll-top + client-height</div>
            <div class="vals"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="each-values flex">
            <div class="mr-2">scroll-top + client-height >= scroll-height</div>
            <div class="vals"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

here i have made a class function to sum up all the work in one function
updated : (when reaching bottom event can be triggered multiple times to avoid this the class function is also tracking last trigger point)

```js
class scroll_bottom {
    constructor(el,obe){
        const obj = this
        this.el = el
        this.lastPoint = 0;
        this.onBottomEvent = obe

        function forScroll(){
            let st = obj.el.scrollTop,
            sh = obj.el.scrollHeight,
            ch = obj.el.clientHeight,
            sp = st + ch,
            scrollEnded = sp >= sh

            if(scrollEnded){
                if(this.lastPoint != sp){obj.onBottomEvent(sp)}
                this.lastPoint = sp
            }
        }
        this.el.onscroll = forScroll
    }
}



// example use 
const main = document.querySelector(".items")
let index = 1
new scroll_bottom(main,function(e){
// #code for scroll bottom here
    main.innerHTML += `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas qui totam vel, et iste autem unde distinctio iure non. Suscipit autem, officiis dolorem eaque rerum quia facere voluptates repudiandae laudantium!`    
    console.log("changed " + index +" time" + (index > 1 ? "s" : ""))
    index++
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- main scroll element -->
    <div class="items mt-5 p-5 border bg-gray-50 w-64 h-36 overflow-y-scroll">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste dolorem doloribus consequatur modi eius necessitatibus. Doloremque, eligendi rerum consequuntur delectus quisquam voluptatum harum, architecto eveniet commodi fugiat aliquid nemo iste?
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste dolorem doloribus consequatur modi eius necessitatibus. Doloremque, eligendi rerum consequuntur delectus quisquam voluptatum harum, architecto eveniet commodi fugiat aliquid nemo iste?
    </div>
```